# Correctly sorting paginated results in oracle SQL

Tags: java, sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have an implementation of datatables serverside pagination.The query builder looks like this:

```
public static String buildPaginatedQueryForOracle(String baseQuery, PaginationCriteria paginationCriteria) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "SELECT * FROM (SELECT FILTERED_ORDERED_RESULTS.*, COUNT(1) OVER() total_records, ROWNUM AS RN FROM (SELECT BASEINFO.* FROM ( #BASE_QUERY# ) BASEINFO ) FILTERED_ORDERED_RESULTS #WHERE_CLAUSE# #ORDER_CLASUE# ) WHERE RN > (#PAGE_NUMBER# * #PAGE_SIZE#) AND RN <= (#PAGE_NUMBER# + 1) * #PAGE_SIZE# ");
        String finalQuery = null;

        int pageNo = paginationCriteria.getPageNumber() / paginationCriteria.getPageSize();
        paginationCriteria.setPageNumber(pageNo);

        if (!AppUtil.isObjectEmpty(paginationCriteria)) {
            finalQuery = sb.toString().replaceAll("#BASE_QUERY#", baseQuery)
                    .replaceAll("#WHERE_CLAUSE#",
                            ((AppUtil.isObjectEmpty(paginationCriteria.getFilterByClause())) ? "" : " WHERE ")
                                    + paginationCriteria.getFilterByClause())
                    .replaceAll("#ORDER_CLASUE#", paginationCriteria.getOrderByClause())
                    .replaceAll("#PAGE_NUMBER#", paginationCriteria.getPageNumber().toString())
                    .replaceAll("#PAGE_SIZE#", paginationCriteria.getPageSize().toString());
        }
        return (null == finalQuery) ? baseQuery : finalQuery;
    }
```

where base_query is the usual string from the dao-impl layer.
It does the job well. However, when I want to sort the results by cnt in the order clause ( this particular case uses the cnt to count the rows of another table linked to every row in the first table like this)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
       SELECT FILTERED_ORDERED_RESULTS.*,
              COUNT(1) OVER() TOTAL_RECORDS
         FROM (
              SELECT BASEINFO.*,
                     ROWNUM AS RN
                FROM (
                     SELECT A.ID_LIST            AS ID,
                            A.NAME,
                            A.DATE_CREATE        AS DATECREATE,
                            A.DATE_UPDATE        AS DATEUPDATE,
                            A.USER_ID            AS USERID,
                            A.TYPE,
                            NVL(
                                   B.CNT, 0
                            )        CNT
                       FROM MAP_S_LIST_ARTS                                                           A
                       LEFT JOIN (
                            SELECT ID_LIST,
                                   COUNT(*) CNT
                              FROM MAP_LIST_ARTS
                             GROUP BY ID_LIST
                     )        B ON A.ID_LIST = B.ID_LIST
                      ORDER BY A.ID_LIST DESC
              ) BASEINFO
       ) FILTERED_ORDERED_RESULTS
        ORDER BY CNT DESC
)
 WHERE RN > (:PAGE * 5) AND RN <= (:PAGE + 1) * 5
```

What I get is that it first takes first 5 rows in another sorting (the default is by id) and then applies the sorting by cnt to them only. for example, if I fetch a page with 5 rows it will sort only among them though I have other pages. What can I do?

Comment: are you really using Oracle 10g which has been out of support for many years?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pagination custom query fetch first N rows error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60709028/pagination-custom-query-fetch-first-n-rows-error)

Comment: No, it is my own question, i just tried another form of the query... and for now yes but I can upgrade it I hope (need to check with boss)

Comment: "What can I do?" You could start by giving us a [MRE] including the DDL statement for your table, DML statements for some sample data and details of your expected output. You say you want to order by `CNT` but you don't really explain what you are expecting or where your query is going wrong. Please give us enough detail so that we can understand what you want (and that includes showing us the input data, the expected output and the errors).